# Trim left space Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, space

I have a wordpress installation whit 841 products. In all this products the product name has a left space so the product name doesnt show in product page.

In the database the most products are showing like ' sample', i want to show all like 'sample'.

The database table name is wp_post and the field is post_title.

How can i remove this spaces? Thanx. I dont know much about databases but if somebody can help me whit this i will be very happy.

I have already tried to fix it whit a plugin but it doenst help.

Thanx already.

Answer (score 1):

The Trim() function will remove spaces from the front and end of a field.  To use it in a query it would look something like the following:

```
SELECT TRIM(productName) FROM MyProductTable
```

If you want to update all of the fields so that they no longer have the space on the front then perform something like the following:

```
UPDATE MyProductTable SET productName = TRIM(productName)
```